# Анаконда не открывает ноутбук после обновления ОС на маке

Tags: python, mac, anaconda

вот так выглядит терминал, переустановка анаконды и перезагрузка результата не дали
[image]

Comment: Попробуйте адрес (`http://localhost:8888/....`) из терминала скопировать в браузер и перейти по нему, и напишите что из этого получится.